# Ngx-datatable cellClass not working

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I try to append my custom css to ngx-datatable cell.

```
<ngx-datatable-column 
  *ngFor="let column of tableOptions.columnDefs"
  [cellClass]="'my-custom-cell'"
  ...
```

Css for `my-custom-cell` :

```
.my-custom-cell{
  padding: 0;
}
```

In dev tools I can see `datatable-body-cell` has classes

```
class="datatable-body-cell my-custom-cell sort-active"
```

Problem is that no css is overridden

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably you're facing an issue about View Encapsulation.

ngx-datatable uses *ViewEncapsulation.None* on it's styling. You can add your *.my-custom-cell* style definition to ./src/styles.(s)css or you can also [set your component's encapsulation to None](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/834#issuecomment-334878690).

You can check details of [view encapsulation from angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) if you don't know about it already.

---

**Edit** *(response for [Tom's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198777/ngx-datatable-cellclass-not-working/47199643?noredirect=1#comment81362209_47199643))*

I also don't want such a solution but unfortunately it seems this is the way...
I've prepared [a demo app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-47198777-1?file=app%2Fdemo-component.ts) which shows what I'm trying to tell.

.my-custom-cell assigned to name column.

.my-custom-cell-global assigned to gender column.

./app/demo-component.ts

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="name" [cellClass]="'my-custom-cell'">
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
    {{value}}
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
<ngx-datatable-column name="gender" [cellClass]="'my-custom-cell-global'">
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
    {{value}}
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

./app/demo-component.scss

```
.my-custom-cell {
  background: red;
}
```

./styles.scss

```
.my-custom-cell-global {
  background: #e6f2ff;
}
```

As you can see red background is not assigned to name column. But gender column gets blue background color.

That's because view encapsulation tells the cli to compile the .my-custom-cell class as shown as below:

```
.my-custom-cell[_ngcontent-c176]{background:red}
```

But [DatatableComponent is using ViewEncapsulation.None](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/d4652065d9b14b1b18608bb8528b920f4b4ee0d4/src/components/datatable.component.ts#L101). If you inspect one of the cells in name column then you can see that datatable-body-cell which has .my-custom-cell class, doesn't have 
[_ngcontent-c176] attribute. So the class is not applied.

If you uncomment [encapsulation line:46](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/d4652065d9b14b1b18608bb8528b920f4b4ee0d4/src/components/datatable.component.ts#L101) then you'll see that [_ngcontent-c176] attribute has gone from compiled .my-custom-cell, and name column gets the style successfully.

Let me know if you find another suitable way.

Comment: [cellClass] or [rowClass] should avoid things like setting ViewEncapsulation to None. This is not what I want.

Comment: The edit is a less suitable solution, because it implies to modify the library. 
However, the response before is good. Thanks !

Comment: I used function to hide the column 

within template file,
`<ngx-datatable-column [cellClass]="showColumn" [width]="20" [flexGrow]="0.5">` 

within code file,
`showColumn({ row, column, value }) {
    return (row.status === 'Open') ? ' hideColumn' : '';
 }`

within styles.scss,
`.hideColumn {
    display: none !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me:

```
:host /deep/ .my-custom-cell {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Its already resolved aand these `deep` or `ng-deep` things looks hacky