# how change a style of ngx datatable column on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I want a add a particular style to a `frozenLeft` ngx datatable column upon scroll. So far what I have achieved is triggering a function call on scroll and setting a flag to true to indicate that the style should be applied.

```
onScroll(event){
    if(event.offsetX > 0){
        this.flag=true;
    }
}
```

But, in ng-datatable column `[ngClass]="{'custom-style': flag}"` is not working (class is not getting appended to the element).
Also tried `[cellClass]` I am not able to figure out how to use `[cellClass]="getClass"` to trigger the change whenever I scroll.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use condition in the `ngClass` and apply the class based on it:

```
<div [ngClass]="flag ? 'applyStyle' : 'noStyle'"> </div>
```

If this doesn't work, there might be an issue with view encapsulation. You need to remove it. You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198777/ngx-datatable-cellclass-not-working) thread, it explains how to do that in simple steps.

Also, make sure your change detection strategy is set to default or make change detection if it is `OnPush` which will update the view properties.

Comment: ```ViewEncapsulation.none``` and ```[ngClass]="{'custom-style': flag}"``` did the magic, but my all other styles are gone, I think it is expecting the styles from global ```style.(s)css```. Without ```ViewEncapsulation.none``` I can use ```[cellClass]``` but it is not dynamic on scroll.  Ideally I need something like ```[cellClass]="{'custom-style': flag}"```. I cant move my styles to global css file.

Comment: Hey, it worked without ```ViewEncapsulation.none```. just had to use ternary syntax like ```[cellClass]="flag ? 'custom-style' : 'none'"```. Can you edit your answer and replace ```[ngClass]``` by ```[cellClass]```, so that I can accept the answer. Thank you

Comment: Yes, the later one is just to give you an idea if things don't work with ternary. You just need to work with ternary thats it. Glad its working.

Comment: You can mark it as accepted for other users. Thanks !